# Infinitely printing upon inserting before an existing element in linked list using C

Tags: c, linked-list

If I insert an element before an existing element then the last two elements keeps printing infinitely. For example, if 10 20 30 are the existing elements and now if I want to insert 40 before 30(so that new list becomes 10 20 40 30) then 40 & 30 prints for an infinite number of times.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}list;

list *start=NULL;
list *create(list *);
list *display(list *);
list *insert_before(list *);

int main()
{
  int n;

    printf("1: Create list\n");
    printf("2: Display\n");
    printf("3: Insert before an existing element\n);
    for(;;)
    {
      printf("Enter your choice: ");
      scanf("%d",&n);

    switch(n)
    {
    case 1:start=create(start);
    printf("\nList created successfully\n");
      break;
    case 2:start=display(start);
      break;
    case 3:start=insert_before(start);
      break;

    default:printf("Wrong input!!!");
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}

list *create(list *start)
  {
    list *new_node, *ptr;
    int num;
    printf("Enter data: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
      new_node=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
      new_node->data=num;
      if(start==NULL)
      {
        start=new_node;
        new_node->next=NULL;
      }
      else
      {
        ptr=start;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
          ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=new_node;
        new_node->next=NULL;
      }
    return start;
  }

  list *display(list *start)
  {
    list *ptr;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
      printf("Empty list");
      return start;
    }
    else
    {
      ptr=start;
     while(ptr->next!=NULL)
    {
      printf("%d\n",ptr->data);
      ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    }
    return start;
  }

list *insert_before(list *start)
  {
    int num,search,flag=0;
    list *new_node, *ptr, *prev;
    ptr=start;
    printf("Enter the number before whom new data is to be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d",&search);
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
      prev=ptr;
      if(ptr->data==search)
      {
        flag=1;
        break;
      }
      ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
      printf("\nEnter the new data to be entered");
      scanf("%d",&num);
      new_node=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
      new_node->data=num;
      prev->next=new_node;
      new_node->next=ptr;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Entered data cannot be found");
    }
    return start;
  }
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: The code you show contains an error that would lead to a compilation error. That means it's not a [mcve]. Please copy-paste your example code into the question instead of rewriting it, as rewriting it could lead to other unrelated errors which might even hide the problem you ask about. Or worse, actually *fix* the error or problem you ask about.

Comment: As for your problem, try to visualize where `ptr` and `prev` are pointing when your search-loop ends. For example, draw up the list using pen and paper, with boxes for the nodes and arrows for the pointers. Erase and redraw the pointers as you "step" through the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked for me.

Comment: @Umang The function insert_before has undefined behavior due to this statement  prev->next=ptr; because the pointer prev is not initialized.

Comment: FWIW, linked lists tend to be quite a bit slower than arrays, because linked lists have poor locality of reference.

Comment: Please don't try to "fix" the code you show as response to comments or answers. That will make the question basically worthless as it no longer have the problem you're asking about. Remember that this site isn't only to help you right here and now, but also for future visitors with the same or a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `insert_before` you should be checked if the first item is the searched and then analyse the other case. Well i did some change and this is the modificated code for in the funtion:

```
list *insert_before(list *start){
    int num,search,flag=0;
    list *new_node, *ptr, *prev;
    ptr=start;
    printf("Enter the number before whom new data is to be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d",&search);
    if(start != NULL && start->data == search){
        printf("Enter the new data to be entered: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        new_node=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
        new_node->data=num;
        new_node->next = start;
        if(start->next == start)
            start->next=new_node;
        else{
            ptr=start;
            while(ptr->next!=start) ptr=ptr->next;
            ptr->next=new_node;
        }
        start=new_node;
    }
    else{
        while(!flag && ptr->next!=start){
            prev=ptr;
            if(ptr->next->data==search) flag=1;
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        if(flag==1){
            printf("Enter the new data to be entered: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            new_node=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
            new_node->data=num;
            prev->next=new_node;
            new_node->next=ptr;
        }
        else
            printf("Entered data cannot be found\n");
    }
    return start;
}
```